# How do I fail the first level?

Tags: achievements, bag-it

I am trying to get the achievement for finding a way to fail the first level of Classic mode.

Problem is, I never seem to fail outright.  I can crush pretty much everything and still get one star.

How do I make sure that I fail?

Comment: Have you tried making sure you don't get any bonuses for item placement?

Comment: @Gnomeslice Yeah. That was my first thing that I tried avoiding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My method to fail the level was as follows:

- Make sure never to get a Sweethearts bonus, i.e. never let **an uncrushed** milk and OJ to be side by side. Once one is crushed it is safe to make them touch. This is very important
- Crush every item in the bag:

  1. Start by crushing one chips bag, easy enough by placing a milk carton on top of it, leave the other chips bag for last.
  2. Crush one milk carton by placing it under the other two
  3. Once you have one crushed carton, place it on top of an OJ box (to avoid the Sweethearts bonus) and place another milk carton on top of the crushed one, side by side, this will crush the OJ.
  4. Crush the other OJ by the same method
  5. Crush another milk carton by placing on top of it an uncrushed carton and two crushed cartons (either OJ or milk work)
  6. Crush the last milk carton, you'll need all the other crushed milk/OJ cartons to do that
  7. Stack the three crushed milk cartons on top of one OJ, leaving two adjacent empty spaces next to your column.
  8. Place the second Chips bag in the two empty spaces, immediately tilt the device towards the chips bag, letting the items crush it.

If you followed my directions you should have 0 points by the end of the level and *successfully fail it*

Answer (score 1):

Are you crushing 'pretty much everything,' or are you actually crushing everything?

The game (level?) gives bonus points at the end of the level.  I haven't figured out if it's for having unbroken items closer to 'lift-off' or for the final height of the items in the bag.

I managed to set up an OJ so that it was the last item crushed, and it got crushed in 2 seconds rather than the usual 4.  I did not receive any bonus points and, therefore, received a score of 0.

It took me a while to fail the level again.  The second time, I crushed the OJ last, in two seconds, and tipped the bag so that everything fell over, and I finished with 20 points.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, crush everything without getting any bonus, make sure the chips is the last, then stack everything leaving a space for the last chip. Hold the chip in the empty space up against the other items, you will discover the chip will countdown even though you are still holding on to the chip. That's a 100% way to confirm you destroy the last chip, rather than letting it go and tilt the bag.

Comment: Just wanted to add, this worked better for me than the accepted answer. I kept getting given 500 points when the level was completed for some reason.